# device token is null when push notifcation are disabled in ios7

Tags: ipad, ios7

I have implemented push notification in my app.it was working fine in ios6. when i updated my app to ios7 i have some issues in push notifcations.
when the app launches below delegate method gets called everytime either notification are enabled or not.
that's fine with ios6.
but in ios7 if notifications are disabled by user this method not gets called 
as a result of this i get device token null.
help me on this.
thanks for any help

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  NSString *strDeviceToken = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
  strDeviceToken = [strDeviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
  self.mydeviceToken=strDeviceToken;
  [appShareData setStrDeviceToken:strDeviceToken];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:K_GETTHEDEVICETOKEN object:nil userInfo:nil];
}
```

Comment: I  also faced the same issue in my application. Did you find any solution for this?